# Conditionally replace values in a data frame with values from another data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a master sheet that I import from an excel sheet and it defines the level of aggregation that my analysis should be conducted at. It defines whether drugs should be rolled up to the drug name or separated out to include the dosage form and strenght.

Here is an example of the master sheet I use

```
df1 <- data.frame(Drug = c("Drug A","Drug B","Drug B","Drug B","Drug C","Drug C","Drug C"),
              Strength = c("All","All","All","All","All","All","All"),
              Dosage_Form = c("All","CAP","SOLN","INJ","CAP","INJ","SOLN"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Drug    Strength   Dosage Form
Drug A  All        All
Drug B  All        CAPS
Drug B  All        SOLN
Drug B  All        INJ
Drug C  All        CAP
Drug C  All        INJ
Drug C  All        SOLN
```

This informs me that sales of Drug A should not be broken out to include the various strengths while conversely Drugs B and C should have separate lines for these two types of dosage forms.

My sales data comes from a data warehouse and the data is pulled at the drug, strength and dosage form level, an example of this data is here:

```
    df2 <- data.frame(Drug = c("Drug A","Drug A","Drug A","Drug B","Drug B","Drug B","Drug C","Drug C","Drug C"),
              STRENGTH = c("80 MCG","80 MCG","80 MCG","80 MCG","80 MCG","80 MCG","80 MCG","80 MCG","80 MCG"),
              DOSAGE_FORM = c("SOLN","CAP","INJ","CAP","INJ","SOLN","CAP","INJ","SOLN"),
              UNITS_SOLD = c(60,100,300,50,20,10,40,20,80), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

And the data looks as follows:

```
Drug   Strength Dosage_Form Units
Drug A  80 MCG  SOLN         60
Drug A  80 MCG  CAP         100
Drug A  80 MCG  INJ         300
Drug B  80 MCG  CAP          50
Drug B  80 MCG  INJ          20
Drug B  80 MCG  SOLN         10
Drug C  80 MCG  CAP          40
Drug C  80 MCG  INJ          20
Drug C  80 MCG  SOLN         80
```

I am looking for a way that I can implement the following pseudo code:

For each drug in `df1` replace the strength and dosage form in `df2` with the respective values from `df1`

My final result should look as follows:

```
Drug   Strength Dosage_Form Units
Drug A  All     All          60
Drug A  All     All         100
Drug A  All     All         300
Drug B  All     CAP          50
Drug B  All     INJ          20
Drug B  All     SOLN         10
Drug C  All     CAP          40
Drug C  All     INJ          20
Drug C  All     SOLN         80
```

Once I have the strengths and dosage forms aligned with the master sheet I can then aggregate the data to the correct levels using group by and summarise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do a join and do the replacement

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[, STRENGTH := "All"]
df2[setDT(df1)[Strength == Dosage_Form], 
          DOSAGE_FORM :=  Dosage_Form, on = .(Drug)]

df2
#      Drug STRENGTH DOSAGE_FORM UNITS_SOLD
#1: Drug A      All         All         60
#2: Drug A      All         All        100
#3: Drug A      All         All        300
#4: Drug B      All         CAP         50
#5: Drug B      All         INJ         20
#6: Drug B      All        SOLN         10
#7: Drug C      All         CAP         40
#8: Drug C      All         INJ         20
#9: Drug C      All        SOLN         80
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df1s <- subset(df1, Strength == Dosage_Form)
i1 <- df2$Drug %in%df1s$Drug
df2$STRENGTH <- "All"
df2$DOSAGE_FORM[i1] <- df1s$Dosage_Form
```

Comment: – Just FYI, although your first answer is a data.table solution, the first line "library(dplyr)" implies it is a dplyr solution!